# Adding a Loop to Macro

Tags: excel, vba, loops

Good afternoon,

I have a pricing model at work that I have to fill out manually in order to determine our forecast. I essentially copy/paste data from one sheet to the next letting the formulas calculate the price shape. I would like to add a loop to my macro to cut down on the manual process.

I would like the data from sheet "**Account list**", one row range at the time, starting with range **`G2:R2`**, copied transposing (rows to columns, columns to rows) into sheet "**Input**" starting on cell **`C10`**. This would generate my pricing. I would then go to sheet "**Output**" and copy the selection **`F5:C28`** and dump it into the sheet "**Load Profile**". I would like to loop it adding the data each time to the bottom of sheet "**Load Profile**" starting on cell **`A1`**, until there is no more data in sheet "**Account List**" i.e. a blank cell in column **`G`** is reached.

Below is what I have so far:

```
 Sub Button2_Click()

  Sheets("Account List").Select
  Range("G2:R2").Select
  Selection.Copy
  Sheets("Input").Select
  Range("C10").Select
  Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= False, _
      Transpose:=True
  Sheets("Output").Select
  Range("F5:AC28").Select
  Selection.Copy
  Sheets("Load Profiles").Select
  Range("A1").Select
  Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, _
      Transpose:=False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

That should get you started. You can make your own adjustements to the code to suit your needs.

```
Sub Button2_Click()

    Dim cll As Range
    Dim lng As Long

    ' Assuming the numbers for pricing are in cells G2:R2 in the Account List sheet
    For Each cll In Sheets("Account List").Range("G2:R2")

        ' Loop thru every number and populate cells C10 on the Input sheet
        Sheets("Input").Range("C10").Value = cll.Value

        ' Find the last row on be Load Profile sheet
        With Sheets("Load Profile")
            lng = .Range("A2", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Row

        ' Copy data from the Output sheet to the first available row on the Load Profile sheet
            .Range("A" & lng).Value = Sheets("Output").Range("F5:C28").Value

        End With

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: This is not quite what I am looking for. Thank you for the comment though. What I really need to be able to do is copy the data from the account list Sheet, special paste it to cell C10 in the Input Sheet, Copy the result in range F5:C28 in the Output Sheet, paste it to A1 in the Load Profiles Sheet, and finally loop back to Account Sheet and repeat, adding the next set of data to the bottom of the first set. This would continue until it reached a blank cell.

Comment: There seems to be a breakdown between what you want to do and what you are describing you want to do.

Comment: @MichalRosa It's [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) :)

Answer (score 0):

## AIOL

```
Option Explicit

Sub AIOL()

  Const cStrAL As String = "Account List"
  Const cStrIn As String = "Input"
  Const cStrOut As String = "Output"
  Const cStrLP As String = "Load Profiles"

  Const cStrRngAL As String = "G2:R2"
  Const cStrRngIn As String = "C10"
  Const cStrRngOut As String = "F5:AC28"
  Const cStrRngLP As String = "A1"

  Dim rngAL As Range
  Dim rngIn As Range
  Dim rngOut As Range
  Dim rngLP As Range

  Dim vnt1 As Variant    ' Array 1: Account List Array, Output Array
  Dim vnt2 As Variant    ' Array 2: Input Array

  Dim lngRow As Long     ' Account List Range Rows Counter
  Dim intCol As Integer  ' Array Columns/Rows Counter

  With ThisWorkbook
    Set rngAL = .Worksheets(cStrAL).Range(cStrRngAL)
    Set rngIn = .Worksheets(cStrIn).Range(cStrRngIn)
    Set rngOut = .Worksheets(cStrOut).Range(cStrRngOut)
    Set rngLP = .Worksheets(cStrLP).Range(cStrRngLP)
  End With

  ' ClearContents of 'Load Profiles'.
  rngLP.Resize(Rows.Count, rngOut.Columns.Count).ClearContents

  ' Assuming data in first column of rngAL is contiguous i.e. spans from the
  ' first row's cell to the cell before the first empty cell.
  For lngRow = rngAL.Row To rngAL.Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row

    ' Paste 'Account List' into Array 1.
    vnt1 = rngAL.Offset(lngRow - rngAL.Row, 0)

      ' Resize Array 2.
      ReDim vnt2(1 To UBound(vnt1, 2), 1 To 1)
      ' Transpose Array 1 to Array 2 (rows to columns and columns to rows).
      For intCol = 1 To UBound(vnt1, 2)
        vnt2(intCol, 1) = vnt1(1, intCol)
      Next

    Erase vnt1

    ' Paste Array 2 into 'Input'.
    rngIn.Resize(UBound(vnt2), 1) = vnt2

    Erase vnt2

    ' Paste 'Output' into Array 1.
    vnt1 = rngOut

      ' Paste Array 1 into 'Load Profiles'.
      If lngRow > rngAL.Row Then
        rngLP.Parent.Cells(Rows.Count, rngLP.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) _
            .Resize(UBound(vnt1), UBound(vnt1, 2)) = vnt1
       Else
        ' Only first run through.
        rngLP.Resize(UBound(vnt1), UBound(vnt1, 2)) = vnt1
      End If

    Erase vnt1

  Next

  ' Clean up.
  Set rngAL = Nothing
  Set rngIn = Nothing
  Set rngOut = Nothing
  Set rngLP = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much for the help!